# Integrate sslcommerz payment gateway in my Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, session, integration, payment

I have already integrated Paypal payment gateway in my django project fllowing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoomN1iY7V9lGJn34sqBgRj2lAuCOYKbs). Now, I want to integrate sslcommerz for users to give more option to pay.

Here are some codes of my project.

config/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-f=f@1a*+svrxj#j8_4ik%c@gd16_s6@c$(n%4p$(66*6g7we6)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'product',
    'user_account',
    'cart',
    'order',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'product.context_processors.categories',
                'cart.context_processors.cart'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =  [BASE_DIR / 'static']
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_account.User'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 86400
CART_ID = 'cart'
COUPON_ID = 'coupon'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'user_account.backends.EmailAuthenticationBackend',
)

# Email credentials
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "azfarshams1998@gmail.com" 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "ecxh vqqd gvhy txwi" 
EMAIL_PORT = 587

#APPEND_SLASH=False

#Paypal Credentials
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = '#####'
PAYPAL_SECRET_ID = '#####'

# SSLCommerz Settings
SSLCOMMERZ_STORE_ID = '#####'
SSLCOMMERZ_STORE_PASSWORD = '#####'
SSLCOMMERZ_IS_SANDBOX = True  # Set to False for live transactions
```

order/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100) 
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms. EmailField(max_length=150) 
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=50) 
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=10) 
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

order/models.py

```
from django.db import models 
from django.conf import settings

from cart.models import Coupon
from product.models import Product


class OrderItem (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='ordered', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        
    def _str_(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.product.title} x {self.quantity}"
    
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
    
class Order (models.Model):
    STATUS = ('Recieved', 'On the way', 'Delivered')
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField (OrderItem)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField()
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    paid = models.BooleanField (default=True)
    transaction_id = models.UUIDField()
    paypal_transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=list(zip (STATUS, STATUS)), default = 'Recieved') 
    created_date = models.DateTimeField (auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_date']

    def _str_(self) -> str:
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

order/views.py

```
import uuid
import json

from django.views import generic, View
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from cart.carts import Cart, Coupon
from product.models import Product
from .models import OrderItem, Order
from .forms import CheckoutForm

# Create your views here.

class Checkout (LoginRequiredMixin, generic. View):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(self.request, 'order/checkout.html', context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            
            print(data)
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': True,
                "errors": None
            })
        else:
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': False,
                "errors": dict(form.errors)
            })
            
class SaveOrder (LoginRequiredMixin, generic. View): 
    login_url = reverse_lazy ('login')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        customer_information = json. loads (self.request.body)
        cart = Cart(self.request)
        coupon_id = cart.coupon
        user_cart = Cart(self.request).cart
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=list(user_cart.keys()))
        ordered_products = []
        
        for product in products:
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                product=product,
                price=product.price,
                quantity=user_cart[str(product.id)]['quantity'] 
            )
            ordered_products.append(order_item)
        
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=self.request.user,
            transaction_id=uuid.uuid4().hex,
            **customer_information
        )
        
        order.order_items.add(*ordered_products)
        
        if coupon_id:
            try:
                order.coupon = Coupon.objects.get(id=coupon_id)
                order.save()
            except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
                # Handle the case where the coupon does not exist
                pass
        
        if float(cart.total()) != float(order.total):
            order.paid = False 
            order.save()
            
        cart.clear()
        
        return JsonResponse({'success' : True})
    
class Orders(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    model = Order
    template_name = 'order/orders.html'
    context_object_name = 'orders'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

order/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    Checkout,
    SaveOrder,
    Orders,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('checkout/', Checkout.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('save-order/', SaveOrder.as_view(), name='save-order'),
    path('orders/', Orders.as_view(), name='orders'),
]
```

templates/order/checkout.html

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Checkout {% endblock title %}
{% block links %}

<style>
    #paypal-button-container{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

{% endblock links %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- Page Add Section Begin -->
    <section class="page-add">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="page-breadcrumb">
                        <h3>Checkout</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <!--img src="img/add.jpg" alt=""-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Page Add Section End -->

    <!-- Contact Section Begin -->
    <div class="contact-section">
        <div id="main-content" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                    <form id="checkout-form" class="contact-form" novalidate method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            {% if messages %}
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                {% include '../message.html' %}
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
                                <small id="error_first_name" class="text-danger"></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Lastname">
                                <small id="error_last_name" class="text-danger"></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
                                <small id="error_email" class="text-danger"></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                <input name="city" type="text" placeholder="Enter City">
                                <small id="error_city" class="text-danger"></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                <input name="zip_code" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zipcode">
                                <small id="error_zip_code" class="text-danger"></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-2">
                                <input name="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter Shipping Address">
                                <small id="error_address" class="text-danger"></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
                                <button class="btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Contact Section End -->
{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_scripts %}

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=#####&currency=USD"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<script>

    const form = document.getElementById('checkout-form');
    const csrfmiddlewaretoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
    let formIsValid = false;
    const paypalCheckout = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
    const mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
    const total = {{cart.total}};

    const validateFormAndCheckout = () => {
        const url = '/checkout/';
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfmiddlewaretoken
            },
            body: new FormData(form)
        })
        .then((response) =>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) =>{
            if(data.success){
                formIsValid = true;
                new FormData(form).forEach((value, key) =>{
                    if(key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'){
                        document.getElementById(`error_${key}`).innerText="";
                    }
                })
                paypalCheckout.style.display = "block";
                form.style.display = "none";
                console.log('valid');
            }
            else{
                let errors = data.errors;
                formIsValid = false;
                new FormData(form).forEach((value, key) =>{
                    if(key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'){
                        document.getElementById(`error_${key}`).innerText="";
                    }
                });
                Object.keys(errors).forEach(key =>{
                    document.getElementById(`error_${key}`).innerText = errors[key].join('');
                })
                console.log('invalid');
            }
        })
        .then((error) =>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        validateFormAndCheckout();
    })

    paypal.Buttons({
        //Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) //Can also a reference a variable or function
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        //Finalize the transaction after payer approval
        onApprove: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! for dev/demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                //const amunt = parseFloat(transaction.amount.value).toFixed(2); 
                const amount = parseFloat(transaction.amount.value).toFixed(2); 
                const transactionId = transaction.id;
                let customer = {};
                new FormData(form).forEach((value, key) => {
                    customer [key] = value;
                })
                delete customer['csrfmiddlewaretoken']; 
                customer['total'] = amount;
                customer['paypal_transaction_id'] = transactionId;

                fetch('/save-order/', {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': csrfmiddlewaretoken
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(customer)
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        mainContent.innerHTML = "";
                        // Show success message
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "Thank you!",
                            text: "Your order has been received",
                            icon: "success"
                        });
                        // Redirect to the orders page after successful order
                        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/orders/';
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                
                //alert('Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details');
                // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL: actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container')
    
</script>

{% endblock extra_scripts %}
```